# How to correct and rewrite this query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id
IN ( 2024 ) 
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM  `used` 
    WHERE DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) , INTERVAL 14 DAY ) <= created)
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM coupon_used
    WHERE code =  'XXXXX')
AND id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM accounts)
```

I have id 2024 in users table, but this id 2024 is there in used tables. So when I run this query, it shows me 2024 id also, which should be filtered out.  I run the query where I selected specific users, and then I want these user to be filter out that they should not be in used table. But above query is not giving me the desire result. Desire Result is that I want to Select Users by following conditions: Take Specific Users, and check that they are not in used table and not in coupon_used table but they should be in accounts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use left joins for the exclusion conditions and a regular join for the inclusions:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN used ON used.user_id = users.id AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= used.created)
LEFT JOIN coupon_used ON coupon_used.user_id = users.id AND coupon_used.code = 'XXXX'
WHERE id IN (2024) AND used.user_id IS NULL AND coupon_used.user_id IS NULL
```

I've edited the date manipulation as well; +7 -14 would be -7 :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try something like this using joins. Which should be easier to read and (depending on the version of MySQL) faster

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM users
INNER JOIN accounts ON users.id = accounts.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN coupon_used ON users.id = coupon_used.user_id AND coupon_used.code = 'XXXXX'
LEFT OUTER JOIN `used` ON users.id = `used`.user_id AND DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) , INTERVAL 14 DAY ) <= `used`.created
WHERE id IN ( 2024 ) 
AND coupon_used.user_id IS NULL
AND `used`.user_id IS NULL
```

EDIT - Simplifying the date check:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM users
INNER JOIN accounts ON users.id = accounts.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN coupon_used ON users.id = coupon_used.user_id AND coupon_used.code = 'XXXXX'
LEFT OUTER JOIN `used` ON users.id = `used`.user_id AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) <= `used`.created
WHERE id IN ( 2024 ) 
AND coupon_used.user_id IS NULL
AND `used`.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Last time user id 2024 added one row in used table was yesterday, so he should be excluded then. But why he is not excluded? According to this `used` ON users.id = `used`.user_id AND DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) , INTERVAL 14 DAY ) <= `used`created

Comment: @Matt Busche - agreed. Finger trouble as I thought I had used an inner join. Fixed now. Ta

Comment: @Akaash - It should exclude it (even with the convoluted date manipulation noted by Jack). Could you post the table declares and sample data?

Comment: I got the reason, in date interval we take interval of 7 to 14, mean it exclude if created from last week to 2 weeks back. But this id 2024 is created yesterday, and its showing because of this reason

Comment: You are not checking an interval, just a specific date. The code takes todays date (2013/03/20) and add 7 days to it (2013/03/27) then takes 14 days from that resulting date (2013/03/13), and checks that resulting date is less than the used created date. However is used.created a date field, or is it a unix timestamp?

Comment: I Have added this one SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id =  '$deb_id'
AND DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) , INTERVAL 7 
DAY ) <= created  but this will give me id from 1 to 7 interval, but if I want to exclude all id which are in this interval then what should i have to do? mean simply Select Ids which are Not In this interval

Comment: The code SHOULD do what you want (although not checking for a range, merely for a date in the past). However if it isn't doing so then that suggests the problem is elsewhere. Possibly with the format of the data, hence the request for the table declares and sample data. Without that we are just guessing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26555/discussion-between-akaash-and-kickstart)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a JOIN on accounts and LEFT OUTER JOINs on the other two tables. A JOIN on accounts means it must be in the accounts table. LEFT OUTER JOINS on the coupon_used and used means it will return a record no matter if they're in that table or not. Filtering down to c.user_id IS NULL means that there is NOT a record in that table.

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
    JOIN accounts ON users.id = accounts.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN coupon_used c ON users.id = c.user_id AND c.code = 'XXXXX'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `used` u ON users.id = u.user_id AND DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) , INTERVAL 14 DAY ) <= u.created
WHERE id IN ( 2024 ) 
AND c.user_id IS NULL
AND u.user_id IS NULL
```